# How to open shell script and update variable value using python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have .sh file (imr_s3_cp.sh) . In this file there is variable SRC_FOLDER. This variable contain some value. I want to update this value and save the file in the same location.

**File contain this-**

```
export SRC_FOLDER=**/imrmnt/vvtransform/csv**

export TRG_FOLDER=s3://itx-acm-eureka-dev-incoming-sourcefiles/imrland/

export LOG=/imrmnt/vvtransform/log/s3_cp.log
```

**I want below things in result**-

```
export SRC_FOLDER=**/imrmnt/vvtransform/csv/CSV_01232019_01232019**

export TRG_FOLDER=s3://itx-acm-eureka-dev-incoming-sourcefiles/imrland/

export LOG=/imrmnt/vvtransform/log/s3_cp.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you intend to save the environment variable, the only option you have is to use `open` and `write`.

Step 1: Read and get lines

```
>>> ev_file = open("/path/to/ev.sh", "r+")
>>> evfile_contents = ev_file.read()
>>> evfilelines = evfile_contents.split("\n")
```

Step 2: Find line with `SRC_FOLDER`

```
>>> linenum = 0
>>> for i in range(0, len(evfilelines)):
...     if "SRC_FOLDER" in evfilelines[i]:
...             linenum = i
...
```

Step 3: Replace that line with new value

```
>>> evfilelines[linenum] = 'export SRC_FOLDER=**/imrmnt/vvtransform/csv/CSV_01232019_01232019**'
```

Step 4: Truncate file.
Note: You can also go to the line and change just that line if the file is too big. I leave that to you to explore.

```
>>> ev_file.seek(0)
0
>>> ev_file.truncate()
```

Step 5: Write new contents

```
>>> for i in evfilelines:
...     ev_file.write(i + '\n')
```

Step 6: Close file to flush buffer

```
>>> ev_file.close()
```

Then you have your new `ev.sh` which you can read in python.